# how to do validation checks in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to perform some validation checks in ADF, if insertion of data fails  it should through error , it will automatically fix the issue in db and pipeline should run

i tired , but not getting , could you provide me with example

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

To perform data validation using ADF , the best transformation available in mapping dataflow is : `Assert transformation`

If the check fails, you can either fail the dataflow by checking the 'Fail dataflow' option or you can use alter row transformation to delete the rows that are failing the checks.

[image]

Checkout the following videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozhHsto-Dqg&t=24s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NzWpTRxt0s&t=503s